# XML conversion fails to JSON return object

Tags: python, ruby, xml, json, csv

I have two files:

- Input [5 start XML](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ccaaj2aymomgqgo/20141004Flemington_5start.xml?dl=0)
- Output [5 start JSON](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ur5q8404dfuukrj/20141004Flemington_5start.json?dl=0)

Please see end of post for minimal XML example.

Note: effectively converting to csv as an alternative to json would be acceptable.
Update - located another command line utility which may assist [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/index.html) from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25372107/461887).

I have tried multiple tools xml2json from [hay](https://github.com/hay/xml2json) [xmlutils for Python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xmlutils) and the Crack gem basically following [this post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3836505):

```
require "rubygems"
require "crack"
require "json"
require 'pp'

myXML = Crack::XML.parse(File.read("20141004Flemington_5start.xml"))
myJSON = myXML.to_json
final = JSON.parse(myJSON,:symbolize_names => true)
pp final 
File.write('test2.json', final)
```

However in every case the same issue occurs. Whenever the XML features this syntax format:

```
<Meeting MeetCode="859382" InputFilename="" GenerationDate="2014-12-05T10:09:53+11:00">
  <RequestInfo RequestCode="" RequestId="0"/>
```

All the values within in this case `<Meeting />` are lost. How do I keep my values when converting to JSON?

```
<json type="object">
  <Meeting type="object">
    <RequestInfo type="object">
```

Minimal XML example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="stylesheet5.xsl"?>
<Meeting MeetCode="859382" InputFilename="" GenerationDate="2014-12-05T10:09:53+11:00">
<RequestInfo RequestCode="" RequestId="0" />
  <CodeType>GALLOPS</CodeType>
  <MeetingCategory>Professional</MeetingCategory>
  <MeetingStage>Acceptances</MeetingStage>
  <MeetingStageEncoded>15</MeetingStageEncoded>
  <MeetingPhase>ResultsConfirmed</MeetingPhase>
  <PhaseMeetingEncoded>63</PhaseMeetingEncoded>
  <NominationsClose>2014-09-29T12:00:00+10:00</NominationsClose>
  <AcceptanceClose>2014-10-01T10:00:00+10:00</AcceptanceClose>
  <RidersClose>2014-10-01T13:00:00+10:00</RidersClose>
  <WeightsPublishing>2014-09-30T00:00:00+10:00</WeightsPublishing>
  <Club ClubCode="10018" Title="Victoria Racing Club" AbrClubDesc="VRC" State="VIC" Category="Metro" />
  <Track VenueName="Flemington" VenueDesc="Flemington" VenueAbbr="FLEM" VenueCode="151" TrackName="Main" TrackCode="149">
    <TrackRating NumericTrackRating="3">Good</TrackRating>
    <Penetrometer>4.83</Penetrometer>
    <RailPosition>+9m Entire Circuit</RailPosition>
    <RailPositionLastMeeting>True Position Entire Circuit</RailPositionLastMeeting>
    <Weather>Fine</Weather>
    <TrackSurface>Turf</TrackSurface>
    <Comments>Finalised 4/10 - 7:45am  Late Scratching Race 3 No. 4</Comments>
    <Irrigation>Nil last 24hrs, 25mm last 7 days</Irrigation>
    <Rainfall>Nil last 24hrs, 4.2mm last 7 days</Rainfall>
    <RacingDirection>AntiClockwise</RacingDirection>
    <TrackInfo>Penetrometer: Inside 4.85, Outside 4.85</TrackInfo>
  </Track>
  <MeetingType>Metro</MeetingType>
  <ApprenticeMeetingType>Metro</ApprenticeMeetingType>
  <MeetDate>2014-10-04</MeetDate>
  <StateDesc>VIC</StateDesc>
  <NumOfRaces>9</NumOfRaces>
  <DayNight>Day</DayNight>
  <TabStatus>true</TabStatus>
  <Logos />
  <XMLSchemaVersion>RISA XML 5.1</XMLSchemaVersion>
  <XMLSchemaVersion>RISA XML 5.1</XMLSchemaVersion>
  <Races>
    <Race RaceCode="5038498" CurrentRaceStage="Results" RaceNumber="1">
      <NameRaceFull StakesGroupId="346">Greenland Australia Maribyrnong Trial Stakes</NameRaceFull>
      <NameRaceForm>MARIBYRNONG TRL</NameRaceForm>
      <NameRaceNews>Maribyrnong Trial Stakes</NameRaceNews>
      <Logos>
        <Logo Id="VOBIS" Reason="Bonus Scheme" Description="Super Vobis Bonus Scheme" Image="VOBIS.png" />
      </Logos>
      <RaceStartTime TimeAtVenue="2014-10-04T12:40:00" AsUtc="2014-10-04T02:40:00" />
      <ClosingTimes UtcOffset="10:00:00.000" Nominations="2014-09-29T12:00:00" LateNominations="2014-09-29T15:00:00" WeightsPublishing="2014-09-30T00:00:00" AcceptanceFinal="2014-10-01T10:00:00" Riders="2014-10-01T13:00:00" Scratching="2014-10-04T07:30:00" />
      <NominationsRaceNumber>1</NominationsRaceNumber>
      <NominationsDivisor>0</NominationsDivisor>
      <GroupType>Listed</GroupType>
      <RaceType>Flat</RaceType>
      <EntryConditions>
        <EntryCondition Type="Class" Id="~" Code="9" Short="" Medium="No class restriction" Long="No class restriction" />
        <EntryCondition Type="Weight" Id="SW" Code="50" Short="SW" Medium="Set Weights" Long="Set Weights" />
        <EntryCondition Type="Age" Id="2" Code="33" Short="2Y" Medium="2-Y-O" Long="Two-Years-Old" />
        <EntryCondition Type="Sex" Id="~" Code="0" Short="" Medium="No sex restriction" Long="No sex restriction" />
        <EntryCondition Type="Ballot" Id="BC7" Code="430001" Short="2YO SW" Medium="Early Season 2YO" Long="Selected Early Season 2YO" />
      </EntryConditions>
      <ApprenticeCanClaim>false</ApprenticeCanClaim>
      <PrizeMoneyDetails TotalExcludingBonuses="120000.00">
        <Prizes>
          <PrizeMoney Position="1" Value="72000.00" />
          <PrizeMoney Position="2" Value="21600.00" />
          <PrizeMoney Position="3" Value="10800.00" />
          <PrizeMoney Position="4" Value="5400.00" />
          <PrizeMoney Position="5" Value="3000.00" />
          <PrizeMoney Position="6" Value="2400.00" />
          <PrizeMoney Position="7" Value="2400.00" />
          <PrizeMoney Position="8" Value="2400.00" />
        </Prizes>
        <Bonuses>
          <BonusDistribution BonusCategoryId="SVG" BonusCategoryCode="6" Scheme="VOBIS" Category="VOBIS - Group/Listed" LongDescription="This race carries a SUPER VOBIS Nominators Bonus of $10,000 for qualified horses." TotalBonus="10000.00" />
        </Bonuses>
        <Trophies>
          <Trophy Recipient="Owner" Position="1" Value="1000.00" />
        </Trophies>
        <StarterSubsidy>0</StarterSubsidy>
      </PrizeMoneyDetails>
      <RaceDistance>1000</RaceDistance>
      <DistanceApprox>false</DistanceApprox>
      <TrackStraight>448</TrackStraight>
      <TrackCircumference>2313</TrackCircumference>
      <TrackRecords>
        <TrackRecord TrackCode="149" RecordCode="436169" RaceCode="5029333">
          <RaceDate>2013-02-16</RaceDate>
          <RaceNumber>7</RaceNumber>
          <DistanceRace>1000</DistanceRace>
          <Time>00:00:55.420</Time>
          <TrackRecordHorse HorseCode="790716" HorseName="Black Caviar" />
        </TrackRecord>
      </TrackRecords>
      <SizeField>16</SizeField>
      <SizeEmergency>4</SizeEmergency>
      <Accepters>12</Accepters>
      <Starters>11</Starters>
      <WeightChange>0.00</WeightChange>
      <RaceEntries>
        <RaceEntry RaceEntryCode="9153413">
          <Horse HorseCode="986313" HorseName="Apoloboom" Colour="BAY" Sex="C" Age="2" NamePrev="" HorseStatus="Active" HasStableReturn="true" FoalDate="2012-08-12" />
          <!--StableReturnCode = 5139732-->
          <TabNumber>1</TabNumber>
          <RaceEntryStatusEncoded>67601</RaceEntryStatusEncoded>
          <HorseOwnership>
            <OfficialHorseOwners>Boom Racing 4 (Mgr J L Travaglia)</OfficialHorseOwners>
          </HorseOwnership>
          <Trainer TrainerCode="11156">
            <Name>Robbie Laing</Name>
            <Location>Cranbourne</Location>
            <State>VIC</State>
            <Postcode>3977</Postcode>
            <Title>Mr</Title>
            <PreferredName>Robbie</PreferredName>
            <Surname>Laing</Surname>
            <Initials>R E</Initials>
          </Trainer>
          <Breeding>
            <Sire HorseCode="726892" HorseName="Kaphero" />
            <Dam HorseCode="752264" HorseName="Apologies" />
            <SireOfDam HorseCode="604480" Country="USA" HorseName="Giant's Causeway" />
            <Breeder>Burnewang North Pastoral</Breeder>
          </Breeding>
          <JockeyRaceEntry JockeyCode="25791" Apprentice="false">
            <Name>Vlad Duric</Name>
            <Location>Pakenham</Location>
            <State>VIC</State>
            <Postcode>3810</Postcode>
            <PreferredName>Vlad</PreferredName>
            <Surname>Duric</Surname>
            <Initials>V</Initials>
            <RidingWeight>53.00</RidingWeight>
          </JockeyRaceEntry>
          <RacingColours>Purple, Yellow V, Purple And Yellow Diagonal Striped Sleeves, Yellow And Purple Stars Cap</RacingColours>
          <BallotSequence>7=</BallotSequence>
          <BarrierNumber>5</BarrierNumber>
          <HandicapWeight>57.00</HandicapWeight>
          <HandicapRating>0.00</HandicapRating>
          <WeightPenalty>0.0</WeightPenalty>
          <Gear Blinkers="true" />
          <BonusIndicator SchemeName="Super Vobis">N</BonusIndicator>
          <Logos>
            <Logo Id="VOBIS" Reason="Bonus Scheme" Description="Super Vobis Bonus Scheme" Image="VOBIS.png" />
          </Logos>
          <Form>
            <FormSummary />
            <ResultsSummaries>
              <ResultsSummary Name="TotalResults" Starts="1" Wins="0" Seconds="0" Thirds="0" PrizeMoney="0.00" PrizeMoneyExBonus="0.00" Bonus="0.00" />
              <ResultsSummary Name="FirstUp" Starts="1" Wins="0" Seconds="0" Thirds="0" PrizeMoney="0.00" />
              <ResultsSummary Name="SecondUp" />
              <ResultsSummary Name="AtThisDistance" Starts="1" Wins="0" Seconds="0" Thirds="0" PrizeMoney="0.00" />
              <ResultsSummary Name="ThisTrack" Starts="1" Wins="0" Seconds="0" Thirds="0" PrizeMoney="0.00" />
              <ResultsSummary Name="TrackAndDistance" Starts="1" Wins="0" Seconds="0" Thirds="0" PrizeMoney="0.00" />
              <ResultsSummary Name="Firm" />
              <ResultsSummary Name="Good" Starts="1" Wins="0" Seconds="0" Thirds="0" PrizeMoney="0.00" />
              <ResultsSummary Name="Soft" />
              <ResultsSummary Name="Heavy" />
              <ResultsSummary Name="Synthetic" />
              <ResultsSummary Name="Wet" />
              <ResultsSummary Name="NonWet" Starts="1" Wins="0" Seconds="0" Thirds="0" PrizeMoney="0.00" />
              <ResultsSummary Name="Night" />
              <ResultsSummary Name="JumpsRecord" />
              <ResultsSummary Name="ThisSeason" Starts="1" Wins="0" Seconds="0" Thirds="0" PrizeMoney="0.00" />
            </ResultsSummaries>
            <LastStartsSummary>9</LastStartsSummary>
            <LastStarts>
              <HorseRaceSummary MtgDate="2014-10-04" VenueName="Flemington" VenueCode="151" AbrVenue="FLEM" RaceNumber="1" RaceCode="5038498">
                <NameRaceNews>Maribyrnong Trial Stakes</NameRaceNews>
                <NameRaceForm>MARIBYRNONG TRL</NameRaceForm>
                <RaceDistance>1000</RaceDistance>
                <GroupType>LR</GroupType>
                <RaceType>Flat</RaceType>
                <EntryConditions>
                  <EntryCondition Type="Class" Id="~" Code="9" Short="" Medium="No class restriction" Long="No class restriction" />
                  <EntryCondition Type="Weight" Id="SW" Code="50" Short="SW" Medium="Set Weights" Long="Set Weights" />
                  <EntryCondition Type="Age" Id="2" Code="33" Short="2Y" Medium="2-Y-O" Long="Two-Years-Old" />
                  <EntryCondition Type="Sex" Id="~" Code="0" Short="" Medium="No sex restriction" Long="No sex restriction" />
                </EntryConditions>
                <MeetingCategory>Professional</MeetingCategory>
                <DayNight>Day</DayNight>
                <ClubCode>10018</ClubCode>
                <ClubCategory>Metro</ClubCategory>
                <VenueCategory>Metro</VenueCategory>
                <RaceStarters>11</RaceStarters>
                <FinishPosition BeatenMargin="8.80" OfficialMargin="1/2 Neck">9</FinishPosition>
                <MoneyRaceGrandTotal>121000.00</MoneyRaceGrandTotal>
                <MoneyPrize>0.00</MoneyPrize>
                <MoneyBonus>0.00</MoneyBonus>
                <Jockey JockeyCode="25791" Apprentice="false">
                  <Name>Vlad Duric</Name>
                  <Location>Pakenham</Location>
                  <State>VIC</State>
                  <Postcode>3810</Postcode>
                  <PreferredName>Vlad</PreferredName>
                  <Surname>Duric</Surname>
                  <Initials>V</Initials>
                </Jockey>
                <BarrierNumber>5</BarrierNumber>
                <Handicap>57.00</Handicap>
                <StartingWinPrice>$13</StartingWinPrice>
                <BettingFluctuations PriceOpen="$11" PriceMove1="$13" />
                <OtherRunners>
                  <OtherRunner FinishPosition="1" Time="00:00:57.960" HorseCode="985390" HorseName="Mihalic" WinningMargin="8.80" Weight="55.00" WeightCarried="55.00" JockeyCode="22573" JockeyName="M J Zahra" Barrier="7" />
                  <OtherRunner FinishPosition="2" HorseCode="983001" HorseName="Iceflow" BeatenMargin="0.75" Weight="57.00" WeightCarried="57.00" JockeyCode="793032" JockeyName="D M Lane" Barrier="9" />
                  <OtherRunner FinishPosition="3" HorseCode="989316" HorseName="Lake Jackson" BeatenMargin="2.25" Weight="57.00" WeightCarried="57.00" JockeyCode="488500" JockeyName="M J Walker" Barrier="8" />
                </OtherRunners>
                <TrackCondition NumericTrackRating="3">Good</TrackCondition>
                <HandicapRatingPreRace>0.00</HandicapRatingPreRace>
                <WeightCarried>57.00</WeightCarried>
                <InRunning Distance="800" Position="5" />
                <InRunning Distance="400" Position="8" />
                <DistanceSectional>600</DistanceSectional>
                <TimeSectional>00:00:33.820</TimeSectional>
              </HorseRaceSummary>
            </LastStarts>
            <AtDistance />
          </Form>
          <LastGear GearType="Blinkers ON" GearDate="2014-09-29" />
        </RaceEntry>
        </RaceEntries>
      <BallotedOutEntries />
      <Comments />
    </Race>
  </Races>
</Meeting>
```

Comment: Your XML example isn't adequate for us to use without making it syntactically correct. It needs a root node and is missing the closing tag for `<Meeting>`. It's nice that you provided a link to more, but you need to include a minimal input example that demonstrates the problem. It's important that you help us help you.

Comment: Thanks I will add some xml the meeting tag is self closing as in the other object tags. I used an xml validation and it said it was correct the file linked that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have **[lxml](http://lxml.de/)** installed in **Python**, you can write a custom parser that make use of *[lxml.objectify](http://lxml.de/objectify.html)* and **Python** dictionary to reserve the values (including date/datetime objects), here is a simple function that can successfuly convert your xml sample and reserve all values as requested:

```
from lxml import objectify
import json

def xml_to_json(f_xml, f_json, indent=4):
    def tree_to_dict(tree, tree_dict):
        _dict = {}
        if tree.attrib:
            # store attrib in dictionary
            _dict.update(tree.attrib)
        elif tree.text:
            _dict = tree.text
        # loop through all the children nodes
        for node in tree.iterchildren():
            node_dict, node_list, _d = {}, [], {}
            # if nested, do a recursion
            node_dict = tree_to_dict(node, _d)
            if not node.tag in _dict:
                _dict.update(node_dict)
                continue
            # use list to append all same name's children node
            if isinstance(_dict[node.tag], list):
                _dict[node.tag].append(node_dict[node.tag])
                continue
            node_list.append(_dict[node.tag])
            _dict[node.tag] = node_list
            _dict[node.tag].append(node_dict[node.tag])
        if not _dict:
            _dict = None
        tree_dict[tree.tag] = _dict
        return tree_dict
    # parse your xml file here, getroot() return the root element
    root = objectify.parse(f_xml).getroot()
    root_dict = {}
    # make use of json module and parse the result dictionary to file
    with open(f_json, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(tree_to_dict(root, root_dict), f, indent=indent)
```

---

Usage:

```
# xml input file path, json output file path, custom indent for json
xml_to_json('sample.xml', 'sample.json', indent=2)
```

Results:

```
$ cat sample.json

{
  "Meeting": {
    "MeetingCategory": "Professional",
    "Logos": null,
    "NumOfRaces": "9",
    "RequestInfo": {
      "RequestCode": "",
      "RequestId": "0"
    },
    "WeightsPublishing": "2014-09-30T00:00:00+10:00",
    "InputFilename": "",
    "PhaseMeetingEncoded": "63",
    "MeetingPhase": "ResultsConfirmed",
    "RidersClose": "2014-10-01T13:00:00+10:00",
    "NominationsClose": "2014-09-29T12:00:00+10:00",
    "CodeType": "GALLOPS",
    "MeetingType": "Metro",
    "MeetDate": "2014-10-04",
    "TabStatus": "true",
    "XMLSchemaVersion": [
      "RISA XML 5.1",
      "RISA XML 5.1"
    ],
    "Track": {
      "Rainfall": "Nil last 24hrs, 4.2mm last 7 days",
      "Irrigation": "Nil last 24hrs, 25mm last 7 days",
      "TrackName": "Main",
      "VenueName": "Flemington",
      "TrackSurface": "Turf",
      "TrackCode": "149",
      "Comments": "Finalised 4/10 - 7:45am  Late Scratching Race 3 No. 4",
      "Weather": "Fine",
      "Penetrometer": "4.83",
      "RailPositionLastMeeting": "True Position Entire Circuit",
      "RailPosition": "+9m Entire Circuit",
      "VenueAbbr": "FLEM",
      "TrackInfo": "Penetrometer: Inside 4.85, Outside 4.85",
      "TrackRating": {
        "NumericTrackRating": "3"
      },
      "VenueDesc": "Flemington",
      "RacingDirection": "AntiClockwise",
      "VenueCode": "151"
    },
    "StateDesc": "VIC",
    "MeetingStage": "Acceptances",
    "Club": {
      "Category": "Metro",
      "AbrClubDesc": "VRC",
      "State": "VIC",
      "ClubCode": "10018",
      "Title": "Victoria Racing Club"
    },
    "Races": {
      "Race": {
        "Logos": {
          "Logo": {
            "Image": "VOBIS.png",
            "Reason": "Bonus Scheme",
            "Id": "VOBIS",
            "Description": "Super Vobis Bonus Scheme"
          }
        },
        "CurrentRaceStage": "Results",
        "TrackCircumference": "2313",
        "NameRaceNews": "Maribyrnong Trial Stakes",
        "Comments": null,
        "NominationsDivisor": "0",
        "Starters": "11",
        "TrackRecords": {
          "TrackRecord": {
            "TrackRecordHorse": {
              "HorseName": "Black Caviar",
              "HorseCode": "790716"
            },
            "TrackCode": "149",
            "RaceCode": "5029333",
            "RecordCode": "436169",
            "Time": "00:00:55.420",
            "RaceNumber": "7",
            "RaceDate": "2013-02-16",
            "DistanceRace": "1000"
          }
        },
        "RaceCode": "5038498",
        "Accepters": "12",
        "RaceDistance": "1000",
        "PrizeMoneyDetails": {
          "StarterSubsidy": "0",
          "Bonuses": {
            "BonusDistribution": {
              "Category": "VOBIS - Group/Listed",
              "BonusCategoryCode": "6",
              "LongDescription": "This race carries a SUPER VOBIS Nominators Bonus of $10,000 for qualified horses.",
              "TotalBonus": "10000.00",
              "Scheme": "VOBIS",
              "BonusCategoryId": "SVG"
            }
          },
          "TotalExcludingBonuses": "120000.00",
          "Prizes": {
            "PrizeMoney": [
              {
                "Position": "1",
                "Value": "72000.00"
              },
              {
                "Position": "2",
                "Value": "21600.00"
              },
              {
                "Position": "3",
                "Value": "10800.00"
              },
              {
                "Position": "4",
                "Value": "5400.00"
              },
              {
                "Position": "5",
                "Value": "3000.00"
              },
              {
                "Position": "6",
                "Value": "2400.00"
              },
              {
                "Position": "7",
                "Value": "2400.00"
              },
              {
                "Position": "8",
                "Value": "2400.00"
              }
            ]
          },
          "Trophies": {
            "Trophy": {
              "Position": "1",
              "Recipient": "Owner",
              "Value": "1000.00"
            }
          }
        },
        "NominationsRaceNumber": "1",
        "ApprenticeCanClaim": "false",
        "GroupType": "Listed",
        "NameRaceFull": {
          "StakesGroupId": "346"
        },
        "SizeField": "16",
        "NameRaceForm": "MARIBYRNONG TRL",
        "RaceType": "Flat",
        "RaceEntries": {
          "RaceEntry": {
            "comment": null,
            "Trainer": {
              "State": "VIC",
              "PreferredName": "Robbie",
              "Surname": "Laing",
              "Location": "Cranbourne",
              "Initials": "R E",
              "TrainerCode": "11156",
              "Name": "Robbie Laing",
              "Title": "Mr",
              "Postcode": "3977"
            },
            "Horse": {
              "HorseCode": "986313",
              "Age": "2",
              "FoalDate": "2012-08-12",
              "HorseStatus": "Active",
              "Sex": "C",
              "NamePrev": "",
              "HorseName": "Apoloboom",
              "HasStableReturn": "true",
              "Colour": "BAY"
            },
            "BarrierNumber": "5",
            "Gear": {
              "Blinkers": "true"
            },
            "Form": {
              "LastStartsSummary": "9",
              "AtDistance": null,
              "FormSummary": null,
              "ResultsSummaries": {
                "ResultsSummary": [
                  {
                    "Bonus": "0.00",
                    "Name": "TotalResults",
                    "PrizeMoney": "0.00",
                    "Seconds": "0",
                    "Starts": "1",
                    "PrizeMoneyExBonus": "0.00",
                    "Wins": "0",
                    "Thirds": "0"
                  },
                  {
                    "Name": "FirstUp",
                    "PrizeMoney": "0.00",
                    "Seconds": "0",
                    "Starts": "1",
                    "Wins": "0",
                    "Thirds": "0"
                  },
                  {
                    "Name": "SecondUp"
                  },
                  {
                    "Name": "AtThisDistance",
                    "PrizeMoney": "0.00",
                    "Seconds": "0",
                    "Starts": "1",
                    "Wins": "0",
                    "Thirds": "0"
                  },
                  {
                    "Name": "ThisTrack",
                    "PrizeMoney": "0.00",
                    "Seconds": "0",
                    "Starts": "1",
                    "Wins": "0",
                    "Thirds": "0"
                  },
                  {
                    "Name": "TrackAndDistance",
                    "PrizeMoney": "0.00",
                    "Seconds": "0",
                    "Starts": "1",
                    "Wins": "0",
                    "Thirds": "0"
                  },
                  {
                    "Name": "Firm"
                  },
                  {
                    "Name": "Good",
                    "PrizeMoney": "0.00",
                    "Seconds": "0",
                    "Starts": "1",
                    "Wins": "0",
                    "Thirds": "0"
                  },
                  {
                    "Name": "Soft"
                  },
                  {
                    "Name": "Heavy"
                  },
                  {
                    "Name": "Synthetic"
                  },
                  {
                    "Name": "Wet"
                  },
                  {
                    "Name": "NonWet",
                    "PrizeMoney": "0.00",
                    "Seconds": "0",
                    "Starts": "1",
                    "Wins": "0",
                    "Thirds": "0"
                  },
                  {
                    "Name": "Night"
                  },
                  {
                    "Name": "JumpsRecord"
                  },
                  {
                    "Name": "ThisSeason",
                    "PrizeMoney": "0.00",
                    "Seconds": "0",
                    "Starts": "1",
                    "Wins": "0",
                    "Thirds": "0"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "LastStarts": {
                "HorseRaceSummary": {
                  "MeetingCategory": "Professional",
                  "AbrVenue": "FLEM",
                  "MoneyBonus": "0.00",
                  "VenueName": "Flemington",
                  "MoneyRaceGrandTotal": "121000.00",
                  "StartingWinPrice": "$13",
                  "Jockey": {
                    "JockeyCode": "25791",
                    "State": "VIC",
                    "PreferredName": "Vlad",
                    "Surname": "Duric",
                    "Location": "Pakenham",
                    "Postcode": "3810",
                    "Initials": "V",
                    "Apprentice": "false",
                    "Name": "Vlad Duric"
                  },
                  "RaceCode": "5038498",
                  "ClubCategory": "Metro",
                  "RaceDistance": "1000",
                  "RaceStarters": "11",
                  "EntryConditions": {
                    "EntryCondition": [
                      {
                        "Medium": "No class restriction",
                        "Short": "",
                        "Long": "No class restriction",
                        "Code": "9",
                        "Type": "Class",
                        "Id": "~"
                      },
                      {
                        "Medium": "Set Weights",
                        "Short": "SW",
                        "Long": "Set Weights",
                        "Code": "50",
                        "Type": "Weight",
                        "Id": "SW"
                      },
                      {
                        "Medium": "2-Y-O",
                        "Short": "2Y",
                        "Long": "Two-Years-Old",
                        "Code": "33",
                        "Type": "Age",
                        "Id": "2"
                      },
                      {
                        "Medium": "No sex restriction",
                        "Short": "",
                        "Long": "No sex restriction",
                        "Code": "0",
                        "Type": "Sex",
                        "Id": "~"
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  "VenueCode": "151",
                  "GroupType": "LR",
                  "InRunning": [
                    {
                      "Distance": "800",
                      "Position": "5"
                    },
                    {
                      "Distance": "400",
                      "Position": "8"
                    }
                  ],
                  "OtherRunners": {
                    "OtherRunner": [
                      {
                        "JockeyCode": "22573",
                        "HorseCode": "985390",
                        "Weight": "55.00",
                        "Barrier": "7",
                        "JockeyName": "M J Zahra",
                        "WeightCarried": "55.00",
                        "Time": "00:00:57.960",
                        "FinishPosition": "1",
                        "HorseName": "Mihalic",
                        "WinningMargin": "8.80"
                      },
                      {
                        "JockeyCode": "793032",
                        "HorseCode": "983001",
                        "Weight": "57.00",
                        "BeatenMargin": "0.75",
                        "JockeyName": "D M Lane",
                        "WeightCarried": "57.00",
                        "Barrier": "9",
                        "FinishPosition": "2",
                        "HorseName": "Iceflow"
                      },
                      {
                        "JockeyCode": "488500",
                        "HorseCode": "989316",
                        "Weight": "57.00",
                        "BeatenMargin": "2.25",
                        "JockeyName": "M J Walker",
                        "WeightCarried": "57.00",
                        "Barrier": "8",
                        "FinishPosition": "3",
                        "HorseName": "Lake Jackson"
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  "NameRaceForm": "MARIBYRNONG TRL",
                  "RaceType": "Flat",
                  "Handicap": "57.00",
                  "HandicapRatingPreRace": "0.00",
                  "TimeSectional": "00:00:33.820",
                  "BarrierNumber": "5",
                  "MtgDate": "2014-10-04",
                  "TrackCondition": {
                    "NumericTrackRating": "3"
                  },
                  "BettingFluctuations": {
                    "PriceOpen": "$11",
                    "PriceMove1": "$13"
                  },
                  "DistanceSectional": "600",
                  "ClubCode": "10018",
                  "RaceNumber": "1",
                  "MoneyPrize": "0.00",
                  "NameRaceNews": "Maribyrnong Trial Stakes",
                  "VenueCategory": "Metro",
                  "FinishPosition": {
                    "OfficialMargin": "1/2 Neck",
                    "BeatenMargin": "8.80"
                  },
                  "DayNight": "Day",
                  "WeightCarried": "57.00"
                }
              }
            },
            "Logos": {
              "Logo": {
                "Image": "VOBIS.png",
                "Reason": "Bonus Scheme",
                "Id": "VOBIS",
                "Description": "Super Vobis Bonus Scheme"
              }
            },
            "HandicapRating": "0.00",
            "BallotSequence": "7=",
            "TabNumber": "1",
            "HandicapWeight": "57.00",
            "JockeyRaceEntry": {
              "JockeyCode": "25791",
              "State": "VIC",
              "PreferredName": "Vlad",
              "Surname": "Duric",
              "Location": "Pakenham",
              "Postcode": "3810",
              "Initials": "V",
              "Apprentice": "false",
              "RidingWeight": "53.00",
              "Name": "Vlad Duric"
            },
            "BonusIndicator": {
              "SchemeName": "Super Vobis"
            },
            "RaceEntryCode": "9153413",
            "HorseOwnership": {
              "OfficialHorseOwners": "Boom Racing 4 (Mgr J L Travaglia)"
            },
            "RaceEntryStatusEncoded": "67601",
            "LastGear": {
              "GearType": "Blinkers ON",
              "GearDate": "2014-09-29"
            },
            "Breeding": {
              "Breeder": "Burnewang North Pastoral",
              "Dam": {
                "HorseName": "Apologies",
                "HorseCode": "752264"
              },
              "SireOfDam": {
                "Country": "USA",
                "HorseName": "Giant's Causeway",
                "HorseCode": "604480"
              },
              "Sire": {
                "HorseName": "Kaphero",
                "HorseCode": "726892"
              }
            },
            "RacingColours": "Purple, Yellow V, Purple And Yellow Diagonal Striped Sleeves, Yellow And Purple Stars Cap",
            "WeightPenalty": "0.0"
          }
        },
        "RaceStartTime": {
          "TimeAtVenue": "2014-10-04T12:40:00",
          "AsUtc": "2014-10-04T02:40:00"
        },
        "EntryConditions": {
          "EntryCondition": [
            {
              "Medium": "No class restriction",
              "Short": "",
              "Long": "No class restriction",
              "Code": "9",
              "Type": "Class",
              "Id": "~"
            },
            {
              "Medium": "Set Weights",
              "Short": "SW",
              "Long": "Set Weights",
              "Code": "50",
              "Type": "Weight",
              "Id": "SW"
            },
            {
              "Medium": "2-Y-O",
              "Short": "2Y",
              "Long": "Two-Years-Old",
              "Code": "33",
              "Type": "Age",
              "Id": "2"
            },
            {
              "Medium": "No sex restriction",
              "Short": "",
              "Long": "No sex restriction",
              "Code": "0",
              "Type": "Sex",
              "Id": "~"
            },
            {
              "Medium": "Early Season 2YO",
              "Short": "2YO SW",
              "Long": "Selected Early Season 2YO",
              "Code": "430001",
              "Type": "Ballot",
              "Id": "BC7"
            }
          ]
        },
        "SizeEmergency": "4",
        "TrackStraight": "448",
        "DistanceApprox": "false",
        "ClosingTimes": {
          "LateNominations": "2014-09-29T15:00:00",
          "WeightsPublishing": "2014-09-30T00:00:00",
          "UtcOffset": "10:00:00.000",
          "Scratching": "2014-10-04T07:30:00",
          "Nominations": "2014-09-29T12:00:00",
          "AcceptanceFinal": "2014-10-01T10:00:00",
          "Riders": "2014-10-01T13:00:00"
        },
        "RaceNumber": "1",
        "WeightChange": "0.00",
        "BallotedOutEntries": null
      }
    },
    "MeetingStageEncoded": "15",
    "ApprenticeMeetingType": "Metro",
    "MeetCode": "859382",
    "DayNight": "Day",
    "AcceptanceClose": "2014-10-01T10:00:00+10:00",
    "GenerationDate": "2014-12-05T10:09:53+11:00"
  }
}
```

---

The output could be a little long, but if you look at the bottom of the output, all values are reversed:

```
...      
"MeetingStageEncoded": "15",
"ApprenticeMeetingType": "Metro",
"MeetCode": "859382",
"DayNight": "Day",
"AcceptanceClose": "2014-10-01T10:00:00+10:00",
"GenerationDate": "2014-12-05T10:09:53+11:00"
...
```

I hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes indeed. I was struggling to find good examples to learn from most b examples are very basic and have little complexities.

Comment: @sayth, yes I had the same feeling in the past too. Only after months of experience and trial and errors + lots of reading, I now understand how to do custom xml/html parser and utilize the existing tools to perform the task in a much easier manner, so hey not a problem I hope I can pass this on to you too! All the best :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this:

```
myXML = Crack::XML.parse(File.read("20141004Flemington_5start.xml"))
myJSON = myXML.to_json
final = JSON.parse(myJSON,:symbolize_names => true)
pp final 
File.write('test2.json', final)
```

should be:

```
myXML = Crack::XML.parse(File.read("20141004Flemington_5start.xml"))
File.write('test2.json', myXML.to_json)
```

If you want JSON output.

Comment: Yeah I serialized my json object in my script